# (JS) For loop, combine object and int var

Tags: json, object, for-loop, var

I'm loading a JSON file with in it some content like this:

```
"forget": {
    "form_elements": 2,

    "input1": {
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "E-mail adres invullen...",
        "value": ""
    },
    "input2": {
        "type": "submit",
        "placeholder": "",
        "value": "Opvragen"
    }
}
```

I'm creating a div of this JSON content, wich all works fine (there is more JSON content but only this is relevant for my question).

After creating the element I'm looping over the inputs using this loop:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= data[get].form_elements; i++) {
        var input = data[get].input+i;

        $overlay.append( $("<input />").attr({
            type: input.type,
            placeholder: input.placeholder,
            value: input.value
        }));
    }
```

Overlay is the  I'll just created.
With this codes there are 2 basic input fields inserted, without a type, placeholder and value. That is because this code doessn't work:

```
var input = data[get].input+i;
```

But when I'm using this:

```
var input = data[get].input1;
var input = data[get].input2;
```

Everything works fine.

When I log the "i" variable in the loop is see that the number **is** ascending.

I also thought that I'll had to covert it to a string with *.toString*, but this also doesn't work.

So my question is, why is this not working? And what can I do about this?
I'll hope I explained my problem well. Thanks in forward.

Comment: You should be able to do it by manually converting it to a String. In that case you should have `var input = "data[get].input" + i;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it is not really a good way: you try to emulate an array using an object.

First of all, your code should work if you do this:

```
var input = data[get]["input"+i];
```

Second, I recommend you to change your content to this:

```
          "forget": {
            "input1": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "placeholder": "E-mail adres invullen...",
                    "value": ""
            },
            "input2": {
                    "type": "submit",
                    "placeholder": "",
                    "value": "Opvragen"
            }
    }
```

And your loop should be :

```
for (var key in data[get]) {
    var input = data[get][key];
    ...
}
```

If you really want to use an array, you should have this as your JSON data:

```
            "forget":  [
                    {
                            "type": "text",
                            "placeholder": "E-mail adres invullen...",
                            "value": ""
                    },
                    {
                            "type": "submit",
                            "placeholder": "",
                            "value": "Opvragen"
                    }
            ];
            for(var i = 0, len = data[get].length; i < len ; i++){
                                    var input = data[get][i];
                ...
            }
```

I recommend you to choose one of the two methods.

Array and Objects are not manipulated the same way so you have to choose which type to use according to your needs.